# How can I force an element of a citation to be displayed in the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to have an "unsorted" bibliography (i.e. order of appearance), but I would also like to show the title of the articles in the bibliography. Can I force bibtex to show the title? Or is there a field that will always show, no matter what, that I can just fill in with the title in my .bib file?

Comment: With traditional BibTeX, the styling of a bibliography depends on the `.bst` you load (usually via `\bibliographystyle{<filename>}`). You should therefore provide more information about what a minimal version of your `.tex` file looks like.

Comment: This is unproblematic. I don't know of any style which does not include the titles of articles in the bibliography. Just use `unsrt` and it will be fine. You don't need to force anything.

Comment: @jon Are there any styles which don't include article titles? Maybe there's some oddball specialist style, but nothing standard will omit this information, surely?

Comment: @cfr - Sure. The journal *Science* does not include titles in the print version of the journal (online version does, however). I think you see it in various of the "hard" sciences, though it is not universal by any means.  I suppose that's why `biblatex-science` has the option `article-title`, and it does say that the style is numeric and unsorted.... (Not that I'll ever be contributing there.)

Comment: @jon But the point is that `unsrt` includes article titles, doesn't it? Frankly I think not including it qualifies a style as both oddball and specialist, but there you go. Probably because I'm not in the sciences.

Comment: @cfr -- Couldn't agree more about styles that don't print title information. But I have no idea what `unsrt` does off-hand. I certainly haven't used it in 10+ years (and never really *used* it beyond seeing what it did). Even if I loved `unsrt` and was a leading `unsrt` expert, though, I might still ask for a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) just on principle.